# Shadows are casting on lighted up surfaces and move with camera

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make comic book like shader with shader graph and custom functions. I almost made all I wanted except that shadows are casting on lighted up surfaces and move when I move the camera: [Video](https://youtu.be/GDnFS53qORM)

I tried to change code of the custom function to get ShadowsAtten from MainLight, but shadows inside the buildings disappeared.

Custom Function Code:

```
void MainLight_float(float3 WorldPos, out float3 Direction, out float3 Color, out float DistanceAtten, out float ShadowAtten)
    {
    #if SHADERGRAPH_PREVIEW
    Direction = float3(0.5, 0.5, 0);
    Color = 1;
    DistanceAtten = 1;
    ShadowAtten = 1;
    #else
#if SHADOWS_SCREEN
    float4 clipPos = TransformWorldToHClip(WorldPos);
    float4 shadowCoord = ComputeScreenPos(clipPos);
#else
    float4 shadowCoord = TransformWorldToShadowCoord(WorldPos);
#endif
    Light mainLight = GetMainLight(shadowCoord);
    Direction = mainLight.direction;
    Color = mainLight.color;
    DistanceAtten = mainLight.distanceAttenuation;
    ShadowSamplingData shadowSamplingData = GetMainLightShadowSamplingData();
    float shadowStrength = GetMainLightShadowStrength();
    ShadowAtten = SampleShadowmap(shadowCoord, TEXTURE2D_ARGS(_MainLightShadowmapTexture, sampler_MainLightShadowmapTexture), shadowSamplingData, shadowStrength, false);
    //ShadowAtten = mainLight.shadowAttenuation;
#endif
}
```

Shader Graph of Object:
[image: Object Shader]
Shader Graph of Outline:
[image: Outline Shader]